# Can Hibernate SessionFactory work with no 3rd part caching systems (Redis, HazelCast, etc)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, session, caching

I've read some articles and questions about Hibernate caching, but I still don't get the concept about SessionFactory caching: is it possible to have and use application L2 cache using SessionFactory without any 3d part systems like Redis or HazelCast? If it's possible, what're the main differences between using "plane" SessionFactory and SessionFactory together with other caching systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate second-level caching is designed to be unaware of the actual cache provider used. **Hibernate only needs to be provided with an implementation of the org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory interface which encapsulates all details specific to actual cache providers.** Basically, it acts as a bridge between Hibernate and cache providers.

You can use Ehcache as a cache provider, which is a mature and widely used cache. You can pick any other provider of course, as long as there is an implementation of a RegionFactory for it.

So If you want to enable second level cache for your hibernate session factory then you have to use third party cache provider like Ehcache.

**What changes needed for L2 cache**

1. Property File Change -

With the following two properties we tell Hibernate that L2 caching is enabled and we give it the name of the region factory class:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

2. Entity level change -

In order to make an entity eligible for second-level caching, we annotate it with Hibernate specific @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache annotation and specify a cache concurrency strategy.

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any ways to use L2 cache without implementing the RegionFactory? I still don't understand the next question: if we manually create SessionFactory and create Session objects in some methods using this SessionFactory, but don't  enable the properties you mentioned, is it still L1 cache? Or it's level two? Could you please explain?

Comment: L1 cache is by Default used by hibernate and there is no way to disabled that. But L2 cache you can enable or disable that. and if you are using only L1 cache then there is no need to implementing the RegionFactory. But if you going to use L2 then you have provide one implementation for that RegionFactory.

Please refer below link for more detailed information - 
1.https://www.journaldev.com/2969/hibernate-caching-first-level-cache
2. https://www.journaldev.com/2980/hibernate-ehcache-hibernate-second-level-cache